# Convert text to number in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, function

I am working on flow for *Incident* object.

**Target field:** There is a field *SomeField__c* in the Incident object. The field type is number.

**Source field:** There is lookup to Contact with field *Name__c* in the Incident object.
There is a field *SomeFieldInContact__c* in the Contact object. The field type in text. That contains numeric values always.

**Update to be done:** Need to update the *SomeField__c* with *SomeFieldInContact__c* in *Incident*.

But flow does not allow that as the type is not same for both fields.

I gave VALUE() function a try but it did not work.

Does Salesforce have a function which can be used in flow to convert Text field to number in flow?

Comment: what do you mean "I gave VALUE() function a try but it did not work."?  Please provide an example of what you have tried and the error which you have received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all Salesforce does not let you equalize number field to string field in flow. You can't even see the fields other than numbers here**

[image: You cant see the fields other than number]

**So you have to create formula variable first** [image]

**as you can see you can parse the string value to number from the lookup here**

**After that all you have to do is set your number fields as the variable you define**
[image]

**I test it in my dev org this flow works. I hope this will help you.**